getting sh: create-###-app: command not found when trying to build an npx create command
Hello Im trying to build out an npx create command but i am getting an error when running the command npx @hydapps/create-matchstick-app no matter what i try i get command not found
here is the package.json
{
  "name": "@hydapps/create-matchstick-app",
  "version": "17.1.5",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },
  "bin": {
    "@hydapps/create-matchstick-app": "bin/cli.js"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
  },
  "author": "Joseph Nwachukwu",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/HydrantApps/matchstickv17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "bulma": "^1.0.1",
    "intro.js": "^7.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.21.0",
    "user": "^0.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.7",
    "prettier": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.10.2"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19+sha1.4ba7fc5c6e704fce2066ecbfb0b0d8976fe62447"
}

and here is the cli.js file
#!/usr/bin/env node

//const {execSync} = require('child_process');
import { execSync } from "child_process";
const runCommand = (command) => {
  //console.log('running command', command)
  try {
    execSync(`${command}`, { stdio: "inherit" });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Failed to execute ${command}`, e);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
console.log("test");
const repoName = process.argv[2];
const gitCheckoutCmd = `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/HydrantApps/matchstickv17.git ${repoName}`;
const installDeps = `cd ${repoName} && npm i`;

console.log(`Getting depenencies from github into folder ${repoName}`);

const getCode = runCommand(gitCheckoutCmd);
if (!getCode) {
  process.exit(-1);
}

console.log(`Code download sucessfull!`);
console.log(`Next, let's install the packages.`);

const installedDeps = runCommand(installDeps);
if (!installedDeps) {
  process.exit(-1);
}
console.log("Congratulations, the install was sucessful!");
console.log(`Now, Let's get coding!!!`);
console.log("Follow these commands to get started");
console.log(`cd ${repoName}`);
console.log("npm start");

its supposed to clone the repo but its not working at all. i already have it published to npm and its in github
